# Exact Target: Send an email based on link click from another email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm wondering if it's possible to send an email to a user when they click a link in an email that was sent out previously.

I've looked at the triggered emails, but this will not fulfill my needs. I have a feeling that the answer resides somewhere in the Journey Builder, but I'm not nearly proficient enough to suss out exactly how to accomplish what I want.

Has anyone done something like this before or have any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Edit: I would like to do this without filtering the users into a list, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What have you tried so far? It's best practice around here to do research and show what you've tried, demonstrating exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The [_Click](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/) System Data View is a record of all clicks by Send Job and Subscriber.  You could write a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to write to a sendable [Data Extension](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) and use that as a target audience for a [User-Initiated Email Send](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/).  All of that can be automated in [Automation Studio](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/automation_studio/getting_started_with_automation_studio/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be easily accomplished by using Engagement split in Journey Builder.

Kindly refer the link below to know more about Engagement split: [**Use the Engagement Split Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/use_the_engagement_split_activity/)